# How to import the data from an Excel spreadsheet so it can be manipulated in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel spread sheet (well, hundreds of them) which I need importing into a database.
If the excel data was in a nice uniform format I would simply save them out to CSV, read them in using something like LINQ to CSV and save the required data away.

However, the excel spread sheet is 'uneven' in that different groups of cells contain different data.
I need a way of grabbing the data and then working with cell references to grab the bits I need and save them to the database.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

UPDATE some more information

I have numerous spread sheets, all identical in structure that need to be imported into a database. The import is not simple in that different chunks of data from the spread sheet will go into different tables. The excel document itself contains a few sections (basically question / answer) type data. For each different section I need to grab the data, shape it into a form that makes sense in terms of the database and save it.

Ideally I would like to create a quick little WPF app that will let me select a spread sheet hit a button and perform the import.

Comment: Start from somewhere else. However you probably need to investigate interoperability with Excel to extract the data cell by cell.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you talking about? Are you dealing with xlsx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who may be interested I ended up using LinqToExcel:
http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Did exactly what I was after with minimal fuss. Excellent

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Excel Object Model to read the data if you do it in a non web environment.
See for example [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).
If it has to be inside a web application. I suggest to use [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx).

Comment: I can run the importer outside of the web environment. Ill check out the Excel Object Model! Looks like it could be good

Answer (score 0):

Turn the Excel Spread sheet into an ODBC (Open Database Connectivity) Data Source so you can access it just like you would any database:

http://www.datamystic.com/datapipe/excel_odbc.html

Then access it just like any database using ODBC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: would that approach work bearing in mind that the excel data is not a uniform block (tabular). I get the feeling I would need more fine grained control

Comment: It wouldn't really work as intended, but once you had access to the data you could write logic to parse through it and throw it into your database as intended. I don't think there'll be an automatic way to handle "uneven" data but maybe someone else will know.

Comment: using odbc or oledb on excel has it limitations. datatypes that don't get recognized, problems with the lenght of cells, etc etc. woudn't go that way when the excel data is bit complicated like yours.

Answer (score 0):

When the data is not uniform, it is often better to keep your approach as simple as possible in the first instance.  Start with vba and the "Range" object (which is part of the excel object heirarchy).  From there you can increase the level of automation and in most instances reuse this "Range" work.

```
  avariable = Range("A2:A5")
```

That notiation is not going to change very much.  It wont matter what final target language you use (language: C# / vba / etc).

There are a number of *other* ways of going about this -- java based / xml based / c# based / and a few other really cool ones that only apply to certain niche situations.  If you can provide more information about your use case, then perhaps I can suggest some more things to try.

---

Q & A

example link for automation from C#: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Comment: Thanks, looking into this now. Will come back with some feedback soon :)

Comment: I don't suppose you know of a link to some documentation do you? I am struggling to find anything that seems quite relevant. Ideally Id like to hit be able to load a excel from a file and grab the data.

Comment: that's the harder path to take.  You are talking interop to unmanaged code from managed code.  When you say hundreds of spreadsheets, are they all a mirror image of each other, or are all different?  Is the call to or from C# automatic or user initiated?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at Microsoft's [Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128771.aspx), which handles a lot of the unpleasant COM/interop stuff for you.